# Why doesn't node.bcrypt.js recognize my password?

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I was thinking of using bcrypt (`npm install bcrypt`) to hash passwords for my node.js application. I decided to make two small scripts as proofs of concept, basically following the instructions from [node.bcrypt.js](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/):

**createHash.js**

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
    password = process.argv[2];

bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function(err, hash) {
    console.log(hash);
});
```

**checkPassword.js**

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
    hash = process.argv[2],
    password = process.argv[3];

bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Trying them out looks like this:

```
$ node createHash.js bacon
$2a$10$Iy8XG2C5.OMysi2S9UK2fu3omruWE4nXnhSKRD2fmNnImEAqayJs2
$ node checkPassword.js $2a$10$Iy8XG2C5.OMysi2S9UK2fu3omruWE4nXnhSKRD2fmNnImEAqayJs2 bacon
false
```

Since I used the same password for both calls (`bacon`), I expected that second call to return true, not false. Can anyone explain why this doesn't behave as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because some shells interpret the `$` in your hash as special characters referring to variables.

To get around this, surround your hash with quotes:

```
bash-3.2$ node createHash.js bacon
$2a$10$i.RiIPW5wSSooTHJI6Sl6usKdx94uAmSUZ8489.os9OKLWGcuO6tm
bash-3.2$ node checkPassword.js $2a$10$i.RiIPW5wSSooTHJI6Sl6usKdx94uAmSUZ8489.os9OKLWGcuO6tm bacon
false
bash-3.2$ node checkPassword.js '$2a$10$i.RiIPW5wSSooTHJI6Sl6usKdx94uAmSUZ8489.os9OKLWGcuO6tm' bacon
true
```